# Using sed or awk to parse current field/column into additional fields/columns on the same line

Tags: parsing, sed, awk

Here are 4 sample rows of the text file of interest

```
EnumerateKey,explorer.exe,HKCR\\Directory\\shellex\\ContextMenuHandlers,NOMORE
CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS
QueryKey,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Control Panel\\International,BUFOVRFLOW       
QueryValue,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\NoRecentDocsHistory,NOTFOUND
```

I would like to augment the rows by appending K fields/columns (for example `K=3` below) which contain the elements of the path found in $3 but parsed by `\\`

Here are the desired output for the 4 lines.

```
EnumerateKey,explorer.exe,HKCR\\Directory\\shellex\\ContextMenuHandlers,NOMORE, Directory, shellex, ContextMenuHandlers
CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS, WINDOWS, system32, verclsid.exe
QueryKey,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Control Panel\\International,BUFOVRFLOW, Control Panel, International,
QueryValue,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\NoRecentDocsHistory,NOTFOUND, Software, Microsoft, Windows
```

After some more study, here are 2 nuances:

Some of the paths begin with HK**, others don't.  However, in both cases I only care about the path that starts after the initial `\\`.  This difference is captured between line 1 and 2.  Therefore I believe the parsing must be anchored at `\\` rather than simply $3 if possible. (Am I using that terminology correctly?)

Second, the depth of the path varies.  In order to keep consistency in column/fields I'm willing to lose some information (line 4) as well as have empty fields for the short paths (line 3) in order to maintain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { split($3,a,"\\\\\\\\"); print $0, a[2], a[3], a[4] }' file
```

Results:

```
EnumerateKey,explorer.exe,HKCR\\Directory\\shellex\\ContextMenuHandlers,NOMORE,Directory,shellex,ContextMenuHandlers
CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS,WINDOWS,system32,verclsid.exe
QueryKey,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Control Panel\\International,BUFOVRFLOW,Control Panel,International,
QueryValue,AcroRd32.exe,HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\NoRecentDocsHistory,NOTFOUND,Software,Microsoft,Windows
```

Comment: You can change the begin block to: `BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=", " }` if you require spaces after each of the split fields. Just as an aside, your expected output is a little inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for this!  For those following along, you can extend the a[i] format to change K as described in the problem description.

Comment: I have edited my desired output in the problem description to remove the mentioned inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

With some ugly Perl:

```
perl -lane '{$l=$_;s/.*?\\\\([^,]*),.*/$1/;@v=split(/\\\\/,$_); print "$l,".join(",",@v[0,1,2]);}' input
```